# Laravel 4 Property of non-object on Nginx

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

I have the following code running on my laptop which is running a MAMP server (so apache). On my system it works absolutely fine, **however**, when I push it to my server it starts throwing "Trying to get property of non-object errors. The databases and migrations are all up to date, and reflect the setup on my laptop. I am wondering why this would be happening on my server and not my laptop. It also seems to happen randomly, which makes me think it's possibly a caching problem?

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    $user = User::where("id","=",$post->posted_by)->first();
    $response['posts'][] = [
        'id' => $post->id,
        'username' => $user->username, //causes problem
        'firstname' => $user->name, //causes problem
        'lastname' => $user->lastname, // causes problem
        'images' => $post->getPostImages(),
        'title' => $post->title,
        'content' => $post->content,
        'price' => $post->price,
        'category' => Category::find($post->category_id)->title //causes problem
     ];
}
```

Comment: Is a post's `posted_by` attribute a foreign key? Are you sure that all `posted_by` users exist?

Comment: You don't have any $user ! So dd($user) to check it!

Comment: @watcher while you're answer wasn't my exact issue, it was the general idea. I found that categories were not being posted correctly and missing the DB id. Thank you for your comment

Comment: I would recommend always check the if thing is exists or not so simply check `if($post)`.its a good practice to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because a category object cant be found

you should change your code to this

```
foreach($posts as $post){
    $user = User::where("id","=",$post->posted_by)->first();

    //check if category id is set
    if(!$post->category_id)
        abort(500,'category_id is not set with Post: #'.$post->id);

    //get the category
    $category = Category::find($post->category_id);

    //check if it found a category
    if(!is_object($category)){
        abort(500,'could not find Category: #'.$post->category_id);
    }

    $response['posts'][] = [
        'id' => $post->id,
        'username' => $user->username, //causes problem
        'firstname' => $user->name, //causes problem
        'lastname' => $user->lastname, // causes problem
        'images' => $post->getPostImages(),
        'title' => $post->title,
        'content' => $post->content,
        'price' => $post->price,
        'category' => $category->title //causes problem
     ];
}
```

This change should help you find out what is missing :)